# Updating the db in the repository from a DTO in a layered architecture

Tags: repository, dto

Given a Person model:

```
Person {
    int PersonId;
    string Name;
    string Email;
}
```

and an UpdatePersonDto which just updates the Name

```
UpdatePersonDto {
    int PersonId;
    string Name;
}
```

How should the repository handle the update process?

1. Accept the `UpdatePersonDto` object, fetch the current `Person` object from the DB, map the fields and then update
2. Accept the `UpdatePersonDto` object and perform an update on the DB just using the DTO. The `Person` domain model is not needed in this case
3. Require the `Person` model and leave the mapping to a higher layer
4. Some thing else?

Comment: Without more detailed context all options are legit. Opinion based answer would second option where you can update field with a simple UPDATE query

Comment: #2 did seem simpler and more performant however most examples I've seen are closer to #1 so I'm trying to understand the reasoning before I get too deep with either option. What additional context do you think would make a difference?

Comment: Additional context: what is the layers of your architecture. If repository is a layer responsible for data access, then #2 looks much better. Then from where this update function called, is this a part of bigger update, or it just pipeline of web API which updating one text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on many factors. For now, I'm going to assume the following layered architecture:

```
Consuming application (e.g. web) > Business > Datalayer > The actual database
```

---

For one, it depends where your DTO lives. Is this DTO create on the business level, or the datalayer level?

- If on the business level, then your datalayer doesn't know the DTO. That means that communication between business and datalayer happens via either domain models, *or* a custom set of primitive parameters (e.g. `Guid personId` and `string newName`).
- If on the datalayer level, then your datalayer can use the DTO, which means that this operates exactly like the "custom set of primitive parameters" situation, with the only difference that instead of custom primitive parameters, you're passing a custom object which acts as the collection of custom primitive parameters.

*Note: it's of course possible to have DTOs on both layers, but the outcome is the same as if you only had a datalayer DTO.*

---

Secondly, it depends on what technology you're using to interact with your database.

If you're using Dapper or any other method where you are crafting the actual SQL query, this gives you the option of writing an explicit update query which only touches the fields you want it to.
However, this becomes more cumbersome when you start dealing with multiple update queries which strongly resemble each other or reuse nontrivial logic. Little by little, it starts violating DRY.

If you're using Entity Framework or any other similar library that means you have the SQL generated for you, you'll generally be better off sticking to the recommended approach for the library you're using. I would assume that any decent library would be able to do targeted updates of only the fields you want to have updated. But since you're dealing with a query generator (the library), you need to use it the way it expects you to use it.

---

Interacting with relational databases via network calls leads to tradeoffs. You're going to either have to sacrifice performance or code cleanliness (to some degree).

As a basic example, consider that repositories were initially intended to operate for one specific entity each. If you want to fetch `Person` and `Car` objects, you'll need to talk to the `PersonRepository` and `CarRepository` respectively.
From a development perspective, this is a really neat and clean way of separating different steps. And when you're dealing with an in-memory list of data, there is no real performance loss.

However, when dealing with a networked relational database, you want to minimize the amount of calls you make because the network calls always cost overhead. If you're trying to fetch a list of people and the cars they own, you're better off launching a single query that fetches both at the same time, and let the database handle the collation of those two entities.

But does that "get both" call belong to `PersonRepository` or to `CarRepository`? That's no longer clear. This means you've compromised your idealistic definition of a repository, because you are now trying to run queries that use multiple entity types at the same time.

This is why it's a tradeoff. Because the performance hit would otherwise be too significant, we trade away the "perfect" repositories in favor of better performance. So when you ask:

> How should the repository handle the update process?

The real answer is **in whatever way that maximizes what is the most important to you**.

> 1. Accept the UpdatePersonDto object, fetch the current Person object from the DB, map the fields and then update

This leads to the cleanest code and ease of development, but it effectively doubles your network calls (fetch + update) which can become a bottleneck.

Then again, if you've got bandwidth to spare and performance is not the #1 priority, but have a limited developer availability, it may be better to favor clean code so you can minimize development and maintenance time as best as you can.

> 2. Accept the UpdatePersonDto object and perform an update on the DB just using the DTO. The Person domain model is not needed in this case

This is the more performant option. It requires handcrafting a update that only targets specific fields, which may lead to more development effort, but it will pay back dividends in performance.

> 3. Require the Person model and leave the mapping to a higher layer

I'm not quite sure how this is different from option 1. I think the only difference here is that you split the "update person" responsibility over two classes.
That *could* be better codewise, but I don't think it's needed (based on my current understanding of your situation) and thus would advise against it.

Performancewise, I'm expecting this to be equal to option 1.

> 4. Some thing else?

Option 1/2 tackle the most common tradeoff: ease of development versus runtime performance. But it's possible that you have other things to consider too (e.g. using a particular approach because your company ubiquitously uses this approach). In such a case, you need to find the approach that works best for your list of priorities.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Cleared up some things. I'm primarily developing apps with no networked db, small team, and something like Dapper. It does sounds like merging the Business and Data layers and using the #1 method would be the best fit most of the time.

Comment: @ChrisHerring: Merging Data/Business makes sense if you're dealing with a rudimentary CRUD rest api; but I'd advise against the merge if there is any nontrivial business logic that is run for a given request. But this is indeed situation dependent :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Only looking for performance, #2 (specific DB update) might look best at a first glance. However, it comes for the price of having to write more SQL code, with a minor violation of the DRY principle. You also have to be more careful if your system supports some local object cache for avoiding duplicate fetches of `Person` objects. And maybe the performance difference is negligible, so simply not worth the hassle.

The decision for or against #3 depends on the responsibilities you want to define for the repos in your system. Ask yourself: if you want to mock out a repository for testing purposes, do you need to mock out this specific "partial update" functionality as well? If the answer is "yes", let the repo take the responsibility for updating, if the answer is "no", find a "higher layer" to do this.

Comment: Thanks. So if you went #3 then in the higher layer you would still need to fetch the Person object first before mapping so I guess it's much the same as #2. The additional fetch did seem redundant, hence my question, but you make some good points for it.

Comment: I miss one thing. #1 is convenient if we consider our application to be the only authority in charge of the data consistency and the business invariants regardless of the performance. If our application is domain-centric (instead of data-centric) these sort of operations happens at the application level and they happen in a more expressive way. Changes are read as objects operations instead of a set of statements that, some times, don't even happen sequentially or take place in the same block of code as in anaemic domain applications with a lot of stateless services.

Comment: @ChrisHerring: you surely meant "it is the same as #1", I guess?That's only true if you exclusively look at the DB operations which will happen, but the question IMHO is also about different responsiblities (for a repo, for other layers etc.) In #1 and #2, the repo takes the responsibility for partial updates. In #3, it does not.

Comment: Sorry I did mean #1. You're right, the difference is in the responsibilities you defined for the layers.